# a way to rotate a spotlight around a specific point?

Tags: lighting

Hey everyone is there a way to rotate a spotlight around a specific point/axis?
i want to see the model being light from different angles and easily rotate the spotlight around the model without moving the model itself. Is this possible?

Comment: you can parent a light to an empty and rotate the empty, if the empty is at the same location as the model the light will turn around

Comment: ... or give the light a _Track To_ constraint on the target

Comment: is it possible for you guys to show me how this is done? maybe a screenshot or something visual?

Answer (score 5):

Start with your model and a Spotlight looking at it.

Add an "Empty: Plain Axes" to the center of the scene (this will be your light pivot). I renamed it to LightPivot to help remember in the outliner

[image: Rot1]

Select the Light then the Empty (pivot), and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> (parent) and select object.

[image: Rot2]

Keyframe the rotation of the Empty at the first frame by selecting it and pressing <kbd>I</kbd> and selecting Rotation.

[image: Rot3]

Keyframe the rotation at your desired end frame (I picked 360 degree rotation at frame 250).

[image: Rot4]

Looks like this:

[image: Spin]

Comment: dam chris, thanks so much ill get to this as soon as i can, youre so cool man!